# How to use a class method in foreach C#?

Tags: c#, python

I've a python code and I want to do the same logic in C#.

```
objList = [objx, objx, objx]
txt = ""
for obj in objList:
    txt += obj.get_xthing()
```

In C# I've this:

```
string txt = "";
List[object] objList = new List[object]();
objList.Add(objx);
objList.Add(objx);
objList.Add(objx);
foreach(object obj in objList){
    txt += obj.get_xthing();
}
```

But I get an undefined method error.
Is there any possible to do the same python code logic in C#?

Comment: `List[object]` is not C# syntax. The type of objects in the list (which in most cases should be something more specific than `object`) should be in angle brackets `<T>`. C# forces you to consider the types of objects you deal with, unlike Python which is rather looser. This is often a good thing, as it tends to surface problems at compile time that in Python will lurk in the code until run time.

Answer (score 1):

The method `get_xthing` does not exist on the [`object` class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.object?view=netframework-4.7.2); indeed, `object` being the base class of all other classes, it has a very limited set of methods available.

In your case, instead of using `object` in the declaration of your list, and in the `foreach` loop, use the actual type of `objx`.

Answer (score 1):

In C# you would use it like:

The class you define:

```
class Foo
{
    private string _Name = string.Empty;

    //Constructor
    public Foo(string name)
    {
        _Name = name;
    }

    //Public Function
    public string GetName()
    {
        return _Name;
    }
}
```

List of objects of the class `Foo`

```
string txt = string.Empty;
List<Foo> listFoo = new List<Foo>();
listFoo.Add(new Foo("Foo1"));
listFoo.Add(new Foo("F002"));

foreach(Foo item in listFoo)
{
   txt += item.GetName();
}
```